# Windows 7: keyboard shortcut to drag windows by clicking anywhere in the window?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

Is there any keyboard shortcut in Windows 7 to be able to drag windows around by clicking not on the upper bar, but anywhere in the window? In GNOME Linux, this can be done by Alt+LeftClick dragging the window, instead of LeftClick dragging the window by the upper window bar.

Comment: Sorry, my typo, left click...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a shortcut but I am not sure how happy it will make you:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> -> will open the move menu than M-> will select move and any key press will move the window 0f at that moment you move your mouse the window is attached and can be freely moved around

But it's way too many keys for me to use it:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> -> <kbd>M</kbd> -> key

than move the mouse around

Comment: Not quite the same quick and efficient solution as offered in linux but better than nothing I suppose

Comment: Thanks, those menus were there in Windows since forever but I only got to know HOW to use them today!

Comment: alt+space does not work with Teamviewer window